# SQL Script fails to set an IDENTITY_INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL script that I run just fine via Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio on my local database. When I commit the SQL and our CruiseControl.NET continuous integration server gets ahold of it, the script has problems. The error:

```
<message level="Error">IDENTITY_INSERT is already ON for table 'BuildDB.dbo.Table_A'. Cannot perform SET operation for table 'Table_B'.</message>
```

Now, this looks simple enough. The quick answer is, "Well, you just need to turn off the IDENTITY_INSERT for Table_A!" The problem is that, in theory, I have. The flow of the script goes like this:

```
BEGIN TRY
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table_A ON
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH
GO

... Do some database insertions ...

BEGIN TRY
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table_A OFF
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH
GO

... Do some other database-y stuff ...

BEGIN TRY
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table_B ON
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH
GO
```

So, the primary question is 'How do I fix this?' The try/catch was my first effort, to no avail. The secondary question, if anyone can answer it, is why would my script work locally but not on the server.

Comment: Why are you swallowing exceptions? Wouldn't it be better to include `SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table_A OFF` into the `Begin Catch/End Catch` section?

Comment: The try/catch was an attempt to fix the problem. Originally, there was no try/catch. The thinking was that, due to the order, it would assume the ability to insert was already on. Which, of course, makes no sense, if I really wanted the IDENTITY_INSERT turned on. But, again, I was just trying things at that point.

Comment: Is it possible that multiple connections are running this code?

Comment: @StuartAinsworth suspects multiple connections (in a multi-user environment) are leading to the problem.  I tend to agree.  I'd try wrapping all of your tsql in a single transaction and get rid of all the `GO` statements.

Comment: Unfortunately, wrapping everything in a transaction resulted in the same thing. I ended up breaking it all up into separate script files and that seems to have done the trick.